# Show custom ErrorDocument when SSL connection fails (SSLVerifyClient)

Tags: apache, openssl, client-certificates

I have configured Apache2 to use Client Certificate AUthentication using:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
```

It works, I can access my site with a valid Client Certificate.
However, when users connect to it without having a ClientCertificate installed, they get a confusing error from the browser.

(Chrome says 'ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR', Firefox says 'ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert', Internet explorer only says 'Internet Explorer cannot display the Webpage'.

I want to show the users a custom ErrorDocument when they try to access without a valid Client Certificate.

The problem is that the site doesn't return a http error code, but aborts the request, so I can't use Apaches' 'ErrorDocument'.

last part of ssl_error_log is this:

```
[Wed Aug 31 11:11:57 2011] [info] [client 192.168.2.156] SSL library error 1 in handshake (server url:443)
[Wed Aug 31 11:11:57 2011] [info] SSL Library Error: 336105671 error:140890C7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate No CAs known to server for verification?
[Wed Aug 31 11:11:57 2011] [info] [client 192.168.2.156] Connection closed to child 1 with abortive shutdown (server url:443)
```

How do I return a valid ErrorDocument for this?

Comment: Migrating to SF at the request of kclement.

Comment: I'm starting to think I can't fix this with apache config, because the request never gets to the Apache server. (connection is aborted by ssl before reaching apache).

Comment: I think what's happening in my case when I run a `chef-client` job is that it's not getting the passphrase to unlock the SSL certificate chain. When I run it interactively it says `Apache needs to decrypt your SSL Keys` so I enter the passphrase so it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SSLVerifyClient optional
RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !=SUCCESS
RewriteRule ^/ http://localhost:8080/missing_cert.html [P,L]
```

Comment: It Works! Thanks.

I can't believe it took me so long to figure out something so simple.
Have since also found another resource with some more info:

http://ryandlane.com/blog/2010/07/29/requiring-ssl-client-authentication-in-a-user-friendly-way-in-apache/